# WPF StringFormat negative value issue

Tags: wpf, string-formatting

I'm using The following format string in a WPF binding:

```
StringFormat={}{0:Gain: 0 dB}
```

And when the bound value goes negative I get:

```
-Gain: 1234 dB
```

My desired output is "Gain: -1234 dB".  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and maybe a couple rules of thumb for using these format strings?

Comment: Should it be `Gain: -1234 dB` ?

Comment: Yes, maybe I should have put that in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
StringFormat='Gain: {0} dB'
```

You can also try it without the apostrophes, if it doesn't work with them in your case.

For more complex cases, you can also consider implementing `IValueConverter` class to use in the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is in the front of the format string.  Move it to the middle and you will have the desired outcome:

Change: StringFormat={}{0:Gain: 0 dB}

To: StringFormat=Gain: {0} dB

So lets say your property is called MyInt with mode = OneWay, this is what the full binding would look like this if you where binding to a TextBlock

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyInt, StringFormat=Gain: {0} dB, Mode=OneWay}" />
```